# Transform font into polygons

Tags: fonts, truetype, cad, freecad

I am working with CAD software (specifically FreeCAD, but this should be system agnostic), and I want to draw 2D characters as polygons - not as strokes. e.g. the letter "O" might be made up of two concentric circles. Is there a way to produce such polygons directly from a .tff file?

(Yes, FreeCAD does support text, but I want to be able to interact directly with the polygons without using the text functionality. This will make the system more portable between certain other programs.)

It looks like you can do this by writing text in a vector graphics program - like inkscape. But that would be a pain: I would have to install the font, write each letter, and manually extract the polygon.

I also tried [this webapp](https://convertio.co/ttf-ps/). It can give me   .svg files, but I still cannot find a systematic way to parse them into polygons.

My goal is to have a function that takes a letter and a scale and outputs a polygon, or list of polygons, that describe that letter.

e.g. in python:

```py
>>> get_letter('O',1)
[[(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)], [(.25,.25),(.75,.25),(.75,.75),(.25,.75)]]
```

The main thing is to get the polygons from an existing font.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in FreeCAD.  I would start by first doing it with the GUI.  Then you can examine the Python console to see what's happening under the hood and modify the python into a macro if you want to automate the process more fully.

First, in the Draft workbench, create a shapestring of the text you want.  Shapestrings can use truetype font, size, and location.

Then select the shapestring in the tree and use the Downgrade tool on the Draft toolbar.  This will explode it into a set of Faces.  Each Face can be further downgraded into a set of wires.  The wires are the polygons you're looking for want.

Under the view-panels menu, turn on the selection view panel.  Then select one of the wires in the tree.  It will appear in the selection panel like 'Unnamed.Wire001 (Wire001)'.  Right click on it and select 'to python console'  This will give you a reference to it that you can interact with in python.
Try looking at Obj.Shape.Wires[0].Vertexes  for a list of the vertices in that wire.